# Metadata doesn't appear

Tags: wcf, configuration, metadata

I'm trying to create a WCF service, but the metadata doesn't appear, i try:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service 
      name ="MyNamespace.IMyContract"
      behaviorConfiguration="mex">
      <endpoint         
        address = ""         
        binding = "wsHttpBinding"    
        contract = "MyNamespace.IMyContract"       
        />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="mex">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I try to access with `http://MyServer/receptor.svc` but shows that `Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.` and `http://MyServer/mex` shows `404`, why? What am i doing wrong?

OBS1: i publish my service in IIS7.5 on Windows 7.

OBS2: if i remove `behaviorConfiguration="mex"` the metadata works, but with `basicHttpBinding` not with `wsHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to put:

```
<endpoint address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```